# Open source C++ library for vector mathematics

Tags: c++, math

I would need some basic vector mathematics constructs in an application. Dot product, cross product. Finding the intersection of lines, that kind of stuff.

I can do this by myself (in fact, have already) but isn't there a "standard" to use so bugs and possible optimizations would not be on me?

Boost does not have it. Their mathematics part is about statistical functions, as far as I was able to see.

**Addendum:**

Boost 1.37 indeed seems to have [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/overview.htm). They also gracefully introduce a number of other solutions at the field, and why they still went and did their own. I like that.

Comment: see my comment below -- boost linear algebra has been around since at least 1.29.

Comment: this question was asked more then 4 years ago. Is there some updates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Re-check that ol'good friend of C++ programmers called [Boost](http://www.boost.org). It has [a linear algebra package](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) that may well suits your needs.

Comment: Seems that part is only in the new 1.37 branch, but I will have a look. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure boost::numeric::ublas has been around since 1.29 or earlier.  His link is just for 1.37.

Comment: indeed, first release is in 1.29, as written by tgamblin: see at the bottom of that page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0

Comment: It is beneficial to compare Boost's UBLAS performance with eigen and others:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark

Answer (score 11):

I've not tested it, but the C++ [eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is becoming increasingly more popular these days. According to them, they are on par with the fastest libraries around there and their API looks quite neat to me.

Comment: Take a look at some benchmarks at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark

Answer (score 5):

[Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/speed.html)

> Armadillo employs a delayed evaluation
>   approach to combine several operations
>   into one and reduce (or eliminate) the
>   need for temporaries. Where
>   applicable, the order of operations is
>   optimised. Delayed evaluation and
>   optimisation are achieved through
>   recursive templates and template
>   meta-programming.
>
> While chained operations such as
>   addition, subtraction and
>   multiplication (matrix and
>   element-wise) are the primary targets
>   for speed-up opportunities, other
>   operations, such as manipulation of
>   submatrices, can also be optimised.
>   Care was taken to maintain efficiency
>   for both "small" and "big" matrices.

Answer (score 2):

I would stay away from using NRC code for anything other than learning the concepts.

I think what you are looking for is [Blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/)

Comment: clearly Blitz++ underperforms with respect to other ones:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark

Comment: It depends on the size and kind of the vector. For small vectors whose length is known at compile time, Blitz++ can generate unrolled code for dot products etc., which can't be beat. Large vectors, where tiling and cacheing is of the highest importance, is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Check [www.netlib.org](http://www.netlib.org), which is maintained by Oak Ridge National Lab and the University of Tennessee.  You can search for numerical packages there.  There's also [Numerical Recipes in C++](http://www.nr.com), which has code that goes with it, but the C++ version of the book is somewhat expensive and I've heard the code described as "terrible."  The C and FORTRAN versions are free, and the associated code is quite good.

Comment: Besides being generally weak, the code in Numerical Recipes also has an odd license attached to its use.

Comment: When using code from Numerical Recipes in C beware of 'exit' statements in the code.
It took me some time to figure out why my application sometimes "crashed" because of this.

Comment: About the book itself I'd say it is well written and explains just as much about a problem as necessary. Concerning the provided code, I agree with David.

Comment: boost::numeric::ublas uses ublas, which is maintained by netlib.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice Vector library for 3d graphics in the prophecy SDK:

Check out http://www.twilight3d.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

For linear algebra: try [JAMA/TNT](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/download.html) . That would cover dot products. (+matrix factoring and other stuff) As far as vector cross products (really valid only for 3D, otherwise I think you get into tensors), I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

For an extremely lightweight (single .h file) library, check out [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/).  It's geared towards image processing, but has no problem handling vectors.